# AWS Route 53 - Setting up forwarding to a Google site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

My domain name campusrover.org is hosted on Route53. It has a main domain name `foo.org`, and a long series of subdomains `abc.foo.org`, all on Route53.

Using an A record, it sends visits to `foo.org` to an S3 domain, which seems straightforward.

This is probably a dumb question but how do I set it up to forward visits to a Google site URL? e.g. `https://sites.google.com/enterprise.com/foobar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS is used to resolve a DNS Name (eg `foo.org`) to an IP address. Then, the actual HTTP request is sent to that IP address.

DNS **does not include paths**, so it is not possible to use DNS to point to `https://sites.google.com/enterprise.com/foobar`.

You would need an API or webserver listening at `foo.org` to redirect the request to somewhere else (eg `foo.org/magic-word/foobar` would send back a Redirect instruction to your web browser to point to `https://sites.google.com/enterprise.com/foobar`).

Comment: I thought it could redirect to a url?